Error Symfony6 : PHP server exited unexpectedly: unable to write pid file: Process is already running under PID 24560
My English is not well so Excuse me.
I got an error with my symfony project. An error with the PHP server. I work on Windows 11. You can see that with the image. It's not the first time it happens.
Error Console
I type a url to access at one of my page and suddenly the server stops.
I went on github and many forums and they said to just shut down and reactivate the server. It worked but after a few minutes the server shut down again. I don't know what to do.
Please help.
